# Authorization error when using YouTube Data API

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube Data API v3, but when I run my script I get following error:

This is the script I'm using:

```
import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    request = youtube.thumbnails().set(
        videoId="EoOUcFHsE9w",
        
        # TODO: For this request to work, you must replace "YOUR_FILE"
        #       with a pointer to the actual file you are uploading.
        media_body=MediaFileUpload("300coin.png")
    )
    response = request.execute()

    print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run this script, I get this in my console:

```
Please visit this URL to authorize this application: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=763961784735-ti8rm4futst2u81hdmnaf803e9gcfm82.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube&state=NQWjaXU1VCruBsePLHo0M8U6eDCsoF&prompt=consent&access_type=offline
Enter the authorization code:
```

When I follow the link, a browser opens with this notification:

```
Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request, urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, can only be used by a Client ID for native application. It is not allowed for the WEB client type. You can create a Client ID for native application at
```

In the ClientId for web applications I use for Authorized JavaScript origins: `http://localhost:8080`. For Authorized redirect URIs: `http://localhost:8080`.

When I go to domain verification and I want to add localhost, I have to write `http://www.localhost:8080` to even get the google verification .html file
but needless to say, the domain `http://www.localhost:8080` doesn't work.
So how do I fix this issue?

All I want is to run a script and update my thumbnails in Python.

Comment: Did you set your Google project to be of type *Web Application*? You're running is not an web  app at all, but a CLI program.

Comment: ok and how do i fix it, cause when i created it i made a web application

Comment: when i set up the oauth credentials i have set it to web app, cause its not a native nor a android app

Comment: Create a new one, with the type mentioned. Later you could delete the initial one.

Comment: But your app is of type *Other UI (e.g. Windows, CLI Tool)*.

Comment: create it with what? its not ios its not native its not for tv and its not a chrome app, so what setting do i use?

Comment: how is it windows app? im using ubuntu. And setting it to windows dont even work. there is no setting type other

Comment: I meant create  a new project within [Google developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/).

Comment: No issue being used on ubuntu; it's a CLI tool.

Comment: Also make sure your redirect URI is `http://localhost` (notice that there's no `www`).

Comment: and when i create 0auth credentials, what settign do i use there? web application or something else

Comment: I have created a new app nad set it to windows cli, but when im asked for 0auth credentials, what setting do i use, web application or something else?

Comment: You have to download and use within your script the client secret JSON file corresponsing to the new project.

Comment: @stvar can you please answer my question? What do i use when setting up the 0auth credentials

Comment: @stvar i know that with the json file, what Im asking is when creating the 0auth credentials what do i use, web application isnt working so  dont know what to use there, i have set it to windows cli when creating the project but the 0auth is still asking me if it is a web application(doesnt work) android chrome tv and some other things, so what do i use there